# Hat History Location

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I think I remember there being a page where I could see what hats I got on prior Winter Bashes.

It was nice to see how I did over the years.    Does this exist or did I dream it?

Answer (score 3):

It does not exist. Sites of older Winter Bashes, e.g. https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/ redirect to 'archive' pages. Leaderboards, or separate profile pages might be saved in e.g. the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/), but there's no Stack Exchange originated mechanism to save them.

To quote the [FAQ](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/faq):

> #### What happens after January 4th?
>
> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense... it must have been one of those rare happy dreams.